# Make ins and outs longer on ports in ciruitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I have the following using circuitikz. I would like to make the lines going from the vertical 2 lines to the inverters be longer. I could create the small sections of lines myself, but I was wondering if there is way to define the length of the in and out pins on the ports (inverters in my case).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \label{fig:lol}
  \begin{circuitikz}


    \draw (0,0) node[scale=0.5,not port] (not0){};
    \draw (0,1) node[scale=0.5,not port] (not1){};
    \draw (0,2) node[scale=0.5,not port] (not2){};
    \draw (0,3) node[scale=0.5,not port] (not3){};
    \draw (0,4) node[scale=0.5,not port] (not4){};
    \draw (0,5) node[scale=0.5,not port] (not5){};

    \draw (not5.in) -- (not4.in) -- (not3.in) -- (not2.in) -- (not1.in) -- (not0.in);
    \draw (not5.out) -- (not4.out) -- (not3.out) -- (not2.out) -- (not1.out) -- (not0.out);

  \end{circuitikz}
  \caption{Controlling the hard disk.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No sorry. I checked and I didn't put any parameter for the length of the connections.

I'd do it like this, though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \label{fig:lol}
  \begin{circuitikz}

   \foreach \x in {0,...,5} {
       \draw (.5,\x) node[scale=0.5,not port] (not\x){}
          (not\x.in) -- ++(-.5,0)
          (not\x.out) -- ++(.5,0);
    }
    \draw (not5.in) ++ (-.5,0) -- ($(not0.in)+(-.5,0)$);
    \draw (not5.out) ++ (.5,0) -- ($(not0.out)+(.5,0)$);

  \end{circuitikz}
  \caption{Controlling the hard disk.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```